# Missing icons in Applications and System Settings in Loki

Tags: release-loki, icons, slingshot

I have a problem with missing icons - I first noticed they disappeared after one of the recent upgrades to Loki.

I have Calendar, Camera, KsystemLog, Screenshot, Videos, Photos and Mail icons missing in Applications. There is a growing sense this list varies but I can't be sure...

They are all fine in plank (though Mail and Calendar seem to share the same icon)

There are also icons missing in System Settings:

Applications, Device Colour Profile, Power, Sound, Online Accounts, Date & time, Parental Control

The missing icons appear as a grey box with bottom left turn up.

I have tried "restore default settings" as suggested in a similar question with no difference.

What can I do to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by doing the command:

```
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop
```

You should get the icons back, but if you were using something like nautilus file manager, then you will have 2 different "files" folders show up in your applications menu.

Comment: The name you see in the Applications menu is the one set by the line `Name=` from the corresponding `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/`.- As  different file managers like Pantheon-Files, Nemo and Nautilus use the line `Name=Files`, having them all installed will show the same name for all. - To change that for Nautilus: `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`, and change that line to something like `Name=Nautilus File Manager`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and `elementary-desktop` was already installed and updated. So, i fixed it by getting `elementary+` via external repository, this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybre/elementaryplus
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementaryplus
```

After that, I launched the application "elementary+ Configurator" and switched on the core-icon theme. Must be an easier way to do that but I just couldn't find it. Hope it works for someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can also manage your Application menu with *menulibre*.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:menulibre-dev/daily

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

Then you can execute `menulibre` in terminal and you’ll get simple GUI to manage you Application menu. Probably that’s more convenient - you can remove apps that you don’t use really and add new apps that didn’t automatically installed desktop entry.