# "Language and Region" disappears in settings menu

Tags: elementary-website

I am new to elementary os and I can't find the "language and region" in my settings menu. Please Help!!

OS:
elementary OS 5.0 Juno
Built on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Linux 4.15.0-69-generic

[image]

Comment: I solved it following this post
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10693/19449

Comment: Hey @Adrian Chau, glad you could solve your issue. It is customary to up-vote the helpful answer, so that others can easily find solutions to their problems. Out of the answers of [this question](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10472/missing-icons-in-applications-and-system-settings-in-loki/10693#10693), which one worked for you?